# What if I get an error Message when building an Game in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

amy be a stupid question, but I'm new to this and now want to build my first game, but if i try this, there is an error message that says:

**Cannot build PLayer while editor is importing assets or compiling scripts**

What can I do about it?

Maybe some of you got an Idea, you could tell me!?

Comment: you just wait until unity completes recompiling. and then go into build menu.

Comment: `Cannot build PLayer while editor is importing assets or compiling scripts` -> wait until it finished importing assets or compiling scripts? If it indeed never finishes there might be some weird editor scripting going on that causes an infinite loop (e.g. something directly modifying script assets on reimport or messing with the global defines)